# The Change of Qiblah

Tags: qiblah

Why was the Qiblah changed from Bayt al-Maqdis (Jerusalem) to the Ka’bah (Makkah)?

And, where and when was that?

Comment: related question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/where-was-the-first-qibla-of-islam?rq=1

Comment: Too many useful links in Google for your question.I think this will help you. [change of Qiblah](http://quransmessage.com/articles/qibla%20FM3.htm) and another is [
Changing the Qiblah and Direction of the Prayer](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=293)

Answer (score 1):

The Jerusalem qiblah was initially imposed on the Muslims in order to fulfill the following Biblical prophecy:

I KINGS 8:41-43

The Prophecy of Solomon

Moreover concerning a stranger that is not of thy people Israel, but cometh out of a far country for thy name’s sake; (a)(For they shall hear of thy great name, and of thy strong hand, and of thy stretched out arm;) (b) when he shall come (c) and pray toward this house. (d)

Hear thou in heaven thy dwelling place, and do according to all that the stranger calleth to thee for: that all people of the earth may know thy name to fear thee, (e) as do thy people Israel; and that they may know that this house, which I have builded is called by thy name.(f)

(Authorized King James)

a)  A person coming in the name of God is a prophet. That this prophet had to be a descendant of Ishmael is made clear in that Allah’s covenant was with Abraham and his progeny. Since this prophet was not of Israel, he had to be a descendant of the other branch of Abraham’s family, i.e., the Ishmaelites or Arabs. Mohammed came out of the far country of Arabia in a miraculous journey that brought him to the site of the temple in Jerusalem. See Quran 17:1.

b)  Because of Mohammed’s preaching, the tribes knew Allah.

c)  The phrase “when he shall come” has two equally valid meanings. This phrase refers to the Prophet’s advent in history as well as his miraculous journey in one night from Mecca to the site of the Jerusalem temple. (The temple structure was destroyed by the Romans in 70 CE).

d)  At the outset of his mission, Mohammed ordered the Muslims to pray toward the site of the Jerusalem temple. He also, during the Isra (miraculous journey) led the prophets in prayer within the temple precincts.

e) Solomon prayed for the success of the Prophet’s mission so that Allah would be known throughout the earth. See Quran 34:28 where Mohammed is proclaimed to be the universal messenger to all mankind.

Once the prophecy was fulfilled, Allah (swt) turned the qiblah toward the Kaba. For more information, please refer to Mohammed, A Prophecy Fulfilled which is found on the Website:  http://arabianprophets.com

And Allah (swt) knows best!

Answer (score 0):

To be simple, at first the Holy place was considered as Baitul Mukadass. Holy prophet was offering his prayer at that time. When while in his prayer, Allah told him to change his position towards the Holy Ka'aba! Since then its the new Qiblah. There are many reasons why it was so. According to me, Holy Ka'aba was the new Qibla for Muslims, as the Mecca was birth place of Holy Prophet too.

Answer (score -1):

This is form a quote by Mufti Ibrahim Desai:

> Some Ulama are of the opinion that the order to change the Qiblah was
>   given before Asr salah, thereafter Nabi (Saw) and the Sahabah (R.A)
>   performed salah to the new Qiblah in Masjidun Nabawi. This is based on
>   a narration in Sahih Bukhari which mentions that the first salah
>   performed by Nabi (Saw) to the ka'bah was Asr salah, which was
>   performed in Masjidun Nabawi. This is the opinion of Allamah Suyuti
>   and Allamah Aalusi. According to them, the Masjid that is famous today
>   as Masjidul Qiblatain , has in fact no real virtue as its supposed
>   significance is based on the fact that Nabi (Saw) turned around to the
>   new Qiblah while performing salah in this masjid. ( See Ruhul Ma'ani
>   Vol.2 Pg.10, Faidul Bari and Darsul Bukhari of Allamah Uthmani)
>
> However, the majority of Ulama say that Nabi (saw) really changed
>   Qibla while in salah. The entire incident is as follows: When Hazrat
>   Bishr ibn Baraa ibn Ma'roor (R.A) passed away, Nabi (Saw) visited his
>   mother who was residing in the area of Banu Salimah. She prepared
>   lunch for Nabi (SAW), thereafter the time of Zuhr salah entered so
>   Nabi (Saw) led the Zuhr salah in the Masjid of Banu Salimah. After
>   completing two rakaat of Salah, whilst in the third rakat, Nabi (Saw)
>   was ordered to now face towards the Ka'bah. which was in the opposite
>   direction to Baitul Maqdis. While in salah Nabi (Saw) turned around
>   and went to the other side (back) of the musjid. The men also turned
>   and stood where the women had been standing, while the women now took
>   what had been the place of the men. In this way, everyone turned to
>   face the Ka'bah. This masjid then became known as Masjidul Qiblatain.
>   This is the opinion of Hafiz ibn Hajr, Allamah Binnori, Hafiz
>   Mughlataa'ee, Hafiz Ainee, Allamah Samhoodi, Allamah Halabi etc. It is
>   also backed up by many ahadith and is attested to by many historical
>   narrations as well as the practice of the people of Madina of
>   according significance to Masjidul Qiblatain. They resolve the
>   apparent contradiction between these narrations and the one in
>   Bukhari, by saying that while the qibla was changed in Zuhr salah in
>   Masjidul Qiblatain, the first complete salah performed towards the
>   Ka'bah was Asr salah in the masjid of Nabi (Saw).(See Fathul Bari Baab
>   no. 30, Ma'arifus Sunan Vol.3 Pg.371, Wafaa ul Wafaa Vol.1
>   Pg.361,363,841, Sharhul Aini ala Abi Dawud Vol.4 Pg.355, Sharhu Ibn
>   Majah Pg.1669, Saheeh ibn Khuzaimah Vol.2 Pg.224,Ibn Sa'd Vol.1
>   Pg.187,As-Seerah Al-Halabiyyah Vol.2 Pg.355 ,Al-Muqtafaa Vol.1 Pg.79,
>   At-Tamheed Vol.6 Pg.484, Ibn Kathir Vol.1 Pg.199,Durrul Manthoor Vol.1
>   Pg.348 etc)

Wallahu alim.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Islam.SE.  We try to discourage posts that directly copy articles from other sites; it would be better to summarize the article and relate it directly to the question asked, with a link to the original site for anyone who wishes to read the whole thing. (*you can read the related meta discussion [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/324/do-we-want-cut-and-paste-answers)*)